# Creating Installation Package in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, installation, package

I'm programming a Qt app in Ubuntu. Well, I'm newbie in Linux but good at Qt. I wanna know how to Create Qt Static Libraries(It's installed from Synaptic), Create an installation package and How to put the app on the Applications Menu.
Please Put some links for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Amir. Unfortunatelly I can't answer your question directly, but I think http://askubuntu.com/ would be the place to ask (it is stackexchange site ;-))

Answer (score 1):

For installing in Ubuntu, you should really create a .deb file for the users to install.  The best reading to learn how to make .debs is the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/), which should work for most .deb based systems.  You could also read some [Ubuntu specific documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete).