# Creating a deb package for Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, deb

I have a Qt/C++ application (I develop it in Qt Creator).

How can I create a deb package for it, that also covers all dependencies?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5497537/62576

Comment: Why not google for [`Creating installation package for Ubuntu`](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Creating+installation+package+for+Ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=nOSKUaLLBMO-Pcz0gMAH) ?

Comment: I think this is a valid question, if there's not a good duplicate, it should be left open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here for a complete package building guide: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/start.en.html